# Protobuff loses data during deserialization

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I'm currently using Google Protocol Buffer to send information with multiple arrays of integers.
The problem is when using 1 object with more than 16 arrays of about 20 elements each, some of the information inside the arrays get corrupted (turned into another number) and the rest of the arrays would be null.
Anyone have a clue why it happens and how i can solve it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look at the help center, in particular [how to ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Please provide a template of your message. Is the ProtoBuf message send via wire, stored on disk or used internally?

Comment: So this is the line of code i'm using. [imgur pic](http://imgur.com/a1GbN8I)
I'm sending it from the client to the server and back.

Comment: Have you checked whether entire message have been send over the network? Note that Protocol Buffer messages are [not self delimited](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#streaming) and doesn't contain information about size of the message. Ps. You should avoid pasting code as image (or any other external resources), its preferred to paste code as part of your question.

Comment: Hell has a special place for people who post code as images :) I'd love to put together a runnable example of it all working fine, but that would be a lot easier with the code as text...

Answer (score 1):

From the image, that is protobuf-net. I find it unlikely that this is a bug inside the library (although I won't rule it out); the most common cause of errors like this are in the calling code (i.e. your bit, the bit we can't see), and include:

- treating the binary data as a string i.e. a text file - and/or using text encodings on data that fundamentally isn't textual
- re-writing buffers without correctly tracking the new end when making something shorter (this applies equally to files, too)
- not reading / writing streams correctly (not checking the return value from `Read`, etc)

If you show the *code you use to read and write*, I'm sure we can find the problem, but I'd wager good money it is one of the above (or something similar).